# Calling asmx web Service from Android errors: "java.io.IOException:HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500"

Tags: android, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to call .asmx web service from Android. Below you can see my code. It's working when I use it for another web service but it doesn't work for one I need to use. 
The problem is "java.io.IOException:HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500" exception. 
Firstly i assume that the problem is from the web service side. However it works when i try to reach using Devexpress and .NET.

I tried to get same error from Devexpress, when I remove "contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"," line.

Note: There is no error at web service definitions.

private class KullaniciServiceAsync extends AsyncTask  {

```
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Kullanici Bilgileri Alınıyor...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected KullaniciBilgisiGetir doInBackground(String... Str) {
        try {
            //ArrayList<HeaderProperty> headerProperty = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();  
            //headerProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")); 
            k = new KullaniciBilgisiGetir();    
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("UserId","1234567890");
            request.addProperty("Password",Pass);
            request.addProperty("Kod",Kod);
            request.addProperty("Sifre",Sifre);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            Log.e("Request",request.toString());
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            try{
                 androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                 SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                 if (response.hasProperty("KResult")) {
                    if (response.getPropertyAsString("KResult") == null) {
                      k.setKullaniciRespond(null);
                    } else {
                      k.setKullaniciRespond(response.getPropertyAsString("KResult"));
                    }
                 }

             }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("httpTRYCATCH", e.toString());
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("ilkTRY",e.toString());
        }              
        return k;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(KullaniciBilgisiGetir e){
        txt1.setText("ResponseText   ->" + e.getKullaniciRespond());
        //txt2.setText("bu "+e.getResponse());
        //txt3.setText("Count "+count);
    }

}
```

Comment: This error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software. It is not a client-side problem.

Comment: How can it be resolved? I can contact with the system administrator. But i should tell him what he need to do.

Answer (score 1):

> **java.io.IOEXCEPTION**
>
> Signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred. This class is
>   the general class of exceptions produced by failed or interrupted I/O
>   operations.

The Web server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request by the client for access to the requested URL.

May be something is wrong at the server end, but the server can not be more specific about the error condition in its response.

therefore it returns it as a error code 500 which means there was an error at server end.

**chances of getting this error might be**

1. The inputs or values that require to be passed for the method on server side and in your code side are different.
2. May be your inputs were right but at some point the server failed to process output at his end and given you the response 500

**How can it be resolved?**

You will have to ask system administrator to check the error log at his end(if any log is used on their side).If the error is logged you will know the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

please check property names are same with web service parameters.

for example;

```
request.addProperty("UserId","1234567890");
```

Is your parameter name UserId on web service ?

also you can follow this tutorial : [Android Programlama – .Net Web Service Kullanımı](http://blog.melihmucuk.com/android-programlama-dotnet-web-service-kullanimi/)